# Nullpointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

There is a possiblity that this may be a dupicate question.
I initialize a String variable to null.I may or may not update it with a value.Now I want to check whether this variable is not equal to null and whatever I try I get a null pointer exception.I can't afford to throw nullpointer exception as it is costly.Is there any workaround that is efficient.TIA

Comment: Maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/how-to-avoid-null-statements-in-java

Comment: Show us the code.  Your explanation does not conform with my experiences.  Also enable null-checks in the compiler if possible (e.g. with Eclipse)

Comment: Forgot to restart the server and that was the problem.Problem solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use

```
if (x == null)
```

you will *not* get a `NullPointerException`.

I suspect you're doing:

```
if (x.y == null)
```

which is throwing because `x` is null, not because `x.y` is null.

If that doesn't explain it, please post the code you're using to test for nullity.

Comment: Ya you got it right.I have the variable y declared as null in X class.However X is not null.No exception is thrown for non null values

Comment: If `x` is not null, then `if (x.y == null)` will not throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: X cannot be null because I am passing X.z to another function as parameter just before this line which is not throwing null pointer exception

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are doing something like this,

```
  String s = null;

  if (s.equals(null))
```

You either check for null like this

```
  if (s == null)
```

A better approach is to ignore the null and just check for the expected value like this,

```
  if ("Expected value".equals(s))
```

In this case, the result is always false when s is null.

Comment: I just typed that same thing!

Comment: I am comparing s==null only.The expected value is anything other than null

Answer (score 1):

String is immutable

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testStringEqualsNull() {
    String s = null;
    s.equals(null);
}

@Test
public void testStringEqualsNull2() {
    String s = null;
    TestCase.assertTrue(s == null);
}
```

Comment: using Java 1.4 no assert or Annotations

Answer (score 1):

> > I am comparing s==null only

can you show the code snippet that you have written 
s==null will never throw a NPE

Comment: You are right...The reason for the exception was I was originally comparing 
s!=null||s.equals("")
 and the or part was throwing nullpointerException.However I removed that but forgot to restart the server.Thanks for ur responses

Answer (score 0):

if you are checking whether "s" is null, then do not apply a dot(.) after "s". Doing that would throw NullPOinterException, as applying dot(.) means that you are trying to access on a pointer location which is basically null at the moment !

Also try to use library functions that check whether a string is null or empty. you may use StringUtils.isEmpty(s) from apache library which checked both