# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a `BlankFragment`

```
package com.hfad.addingafragmenttoframelayout;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("message","onCreateView() of BlankFragment");
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

    public void setText(String textToBeSet){
        TextView tv = (TextView)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.fragmentText);
        tv.setText(textToBeSet);
    }

}
```

and it's layout is:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hfad.addingafragmenttoframelayout.BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentText"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the `MainActivity`

```
package com.hfad.addingafragmenttoframelayout;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //BlankFragment bf = new BlankFragment();
        //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, bf).commit();

        BlankFragment bf = new BlankFragment();
        bf.setText("hello world");
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, bf).commit();


    }




}
```

and here is the layout of `MainActivity`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.hfad.addingafragmenttoframelayout.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

In the onCreate method of activity I am adding fragment to layout. This works fine unless I try to change the Text using setText method.

And I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                           at com.hfad.addingafragmenttoframelayout.BlankFragment.setText(BlankFragment.java:35)
                                                                                           at com.hfad.addingafragmenttoframelayout.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:29)
```

referring to this line

```
TextView tv = (TextView)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.fragmentText);
```

Can somebody explain what's causing this exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nullpointer exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277684/nullpointer-exception)

Comment: Try use  bf.setText("hello world"); after you've done getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, bf).commit();

Answer (score 24):

**Don't**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("message","onCreateView() of BlankFragment");
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
}

public void setText(String textToBeSet){
    TextView tv = (TextView)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.fragmentText);
    tv.setText(textToBeSet);
}
```

**Do**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    
    TextView tv = (TextView)RootView.findViewById(R.id.fragmentText);
    tv.setText("HI");
    
    return RootView;
}
```

Comment: I get your point, but thing is as I am creating `BlankFragment's` object myself hence `onCreateView` isn't called. Is there a way to call Fragment's life cycle method while instantiating object?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
bf.setText("hello world");
```

line causing issue, becuase calling `setText` method of Fragment before adding `Fragment` in `FragmentManager`.

Call `setText` method after adding `bf` Fragment:

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
    add(R.id.fragment_container, bf).commit();
    bf.setText("hello world"); // call here
```

Comment: This did not make any difference. I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is FragmentTransaction is async by default

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, BlankFragment.newInstance);
ft.disallowBackStack();
ft.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
```

Then you still can't get the Fragment yet, you have to get it from the FragmentTransaction

```
BlankFragment bf = (BlankFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
bf.setText("hello world");
```

This [article](http://nikoyuwono.com/2016/12/13/fragment-transaction-commitnow/) helped me to understand this problem better

Comment: Thanks, but it's about `commitNow()`, not `commit()`. In your case, you are right, a problem in setting a text too early. You should set it in `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()` of a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv = (TextView)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.fragmentText);
```

do it in onCreateView();

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary variable that can hold the `String` while the View is not yet created.

```
private TextView tv;
private String holder = ""; 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container,false);

    tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.fragmentText);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   tv.setText(holder);
}

public void setText(String textToBeSet){
    if(tv != null){
       tv.setText(textToBeSet);
    }else{
       holder = textToBeSet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you want to instantiate your `BlankFragment` with some initial text as well as allowing the text to be set later on from your `MainActivity`.

In that case I would first change the the Fragment to accept an initial text like so:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_INITIAL_TEXT = "arg_initial_text";

    public static BlankFragment newInstance(CharSequence initialText) {
        final BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        final Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putCharSequence(ARG_INITIAL_TEXT, initialText);

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private CharSequence mInitialText;
    private TextView mText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mInitialText = getArguments().getCharSequence(ARG_INITIAL_TEXT);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("message", "onCreateView() of BlankFragment");
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mText = view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentText);

        mText.setText(mInitialText);
    }

    public void setText(CharSequence textToBeSet) {
        mText.setText(textToBeSet);
    }
}
```

The Activity code would then look like the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BlankFragment mBlankFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            final Fragment bf = BlankFragment.newInstance("hello world");
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, bf, BlankFragment.class.getName())
                    .commit();
        }

        mBlankFragment = (BlankFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(BlankFragment.class.getName());
    }

    private void someTimeLaterWhenWantingToSetNewTextToFragmentFromActivity(CharSequence newText) {
        if (mBlankFragment != null) {
            mBlankFragment.setText(newText);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the null-check of `savedInstanceState` is to guard for Activity-recreation for instance due to configuration changes.