# NullPointerException on ImageView in Fragment in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I have a bunch of fragments in a FragmentPagerAdapter with one ImageView in side each fragment. If I swipe really fast this error comes up:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                Process: com.wilsapp.wilsapp, PID: 21319
                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                at com.wilsapp.wilsapp.Fragments.BuyerHomePageFragment9$DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(BuyerHomePageFragment9.java:212)
                at com.wilsapp.wilsapp.Fragments.BuyerHomePageFragment9$DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(BuyerHomePageFragment9.java:192)
                at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

If I swipe slowly then it works perfectly fine.

Android Code (code is the same for each fragment. Code in AsyncTask):

```
   protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    try {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ProductOneImageView);
        img.setImageBitmap(result);
    }catch (Exception e){
        ImageView img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ProductOneImageView);
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("com.wilsapp.wilsapp:drawable/" + "error", null, null);
        img.setImageResource(id);
    }
}
```

Android onCreatView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buyer_home_page, container, false);

    return view;
}
```

> how can i avoid the NullPointerException?

Comment: post you xml code and full code of fragment

Comment: put try catch code into OnCreate() method ..............

Comment: use onCreateView to initialize your ImageView.

Comment: Hi Make sure your findViewByIdonly called when the view is created otherwise it throw null pointer exception because they could not able to find the id inside the fragment

Comment: Here is the same problem and solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177999/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-view-v

Comment: @sushildlh still tells me that NullPointerException may happen

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela still tells me that NullPointerException may happen

Comment: that try catch is in the 'onPostExecute' method in a 'AsyncTask'

Comment: @LazarK after `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buyer_home_page, container, false);` you have to put your code for initializing `ImageView img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ProductOneImageView);`. Declare ImageView img so is available to internal classes.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela remove the getView() and add view and then it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ProductFiveImageView);
```

ImageView need initialize in onCreateView. A case of you `getView()` return null...

Answer (score 0):

Add your initialization snippet in `onViewCreated` method instead of `onCreateView`. it will ensure that `imageview` will be initialize after your view is inflated.

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ProductFiveImageView);
            img.setImageBitmap(result);

}
```

Comment: what if i use a 'onCreateView' method?

Comment: if you change the method to mine then I'll mark it correct

Comment: I dont know what is issue with this method? you can use it if it will resolve your issue.`onViewCreated` will call after your view is created so your view will never null if this method getting call if you inflate view properly . so give it a try @LazarK

Comment: because it isnt the method i used in my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ProductFiveImageView);
```

hi You can add a judgment,getView  Whether to null， and Fault tolerant processing!

Comment: what this made no sense?

Comment: Because  I think the problem is in getView()  return null  , And then make a judgment.

Comment: Example ：  if( getView() != null){ImageView img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ProductFiveImageView);}

Comment: Your question is this every time? Because I have encountered similar problems, is to make a judgment to solve the problem, if you do not solve your problem is very sorry!